# Co-dimension one linear subvarieties of hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is perhaps a very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer after a quick literature review. Let $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ with $n \geq 3$ be a non-singular hypersurface of degree $d \geq 3$. Is it known whether the number of co-dimension one linear subvarieties of $X$ is finite? If it is known to be finite, then is there a uniform bound for the number of co-dimension one subvarieties that only depend on $d$ and $n$?

When $n = 3$. This is known. Indeed, a theorem of Segre states that any surface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ contains at most $(d-2)(11d-6)$ lines. A bound like this was known already to Salmon in the 19th century. There is of course the well-known result of Cayley and Salmon which states that any cubic surface contains exactly 27 lines (counted with multiplicity).

Comment: Your hypothesis "geometrically irreducible" doesn't rule out the case of a surface in $\mathbf P^3$ which is a cone over a degree $d$ curve, but obviously the result of Segre does not apply in that case. Can you clarify exactly what kind of $X$ you are asking about?

Comment: @Bort thank you for pointing that out. I am not well-versed enough with algebraic geometry to formulate something too precise, but I think assuming that $X$ is non-singular should rule out all of these abnormalities (I thought geometrically irreducible would suffice, but clearly not!)

Comment: An elementary argument shows that a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$ which contains a codimension 1 linear subvariety must have a singular locus of dimension $\geq n-4$; in particular it must be singular as soon as $n\geq 4$.

Comment: There is an extension of the Salmon-Segre result to smooth hypersurfaces of dimension $2m$ and degree $d\geq 3$: there are only finitely many linear subvarieties of dimension $m$ contained in the hypersurface.  This was proved independently by Olivier Debarre and myself, cf. appendix to the following, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505186  The method that I use gives an upper bound on the number, but it is probably far from sharp.

Comment: @abx Could you please sketch the elementary argument or at least a hint?

Comment: @Zach Teitler: if the linear subspace is defined by $X=Y=0$, the equation of the hypersurface is of the form $XF+YG=0$; by the Jacobian criterion, the subvariety $X=Y=F=G=0$ is singular.